# Storing attributes in a STL container?

Tags: c++, templates, boost-mpl

Suppose I have a class called generic_pair of the form:

```
template < typename K, typename V >
struct generic_pair{
  K key;
  V value;
};
```

Now, the problem is I would like to be able to store a bunch of these generic_pairs in an STL container *BUT* not all < K, V > in the container will be of the same type. For example, some elements may be < int, int > whereas others may be < int , string > and so on. Question is how can we do this?

My first thought is to use "tags" to create a hierarchy of encapsulated types and declare the container with the generic type but actual elements with inherited types. For example,

```
struct base_type{
  typedef void type;
};

struct int_type: base_type{
  typedef int type;
}

struct string_type: base_type{
  typedef std::string type;
}

/// and so on establish a type hierarchy as necessary and then...

std::vector < generic_pair < base_type, base_type > > vec;
```

I bet there is a better, more correct way to do this? Any ideas, directions appreciated. If you have seen similar implementations or relevant tools/techniques in MPL or elsewhere that's helpful too. (I am trying to avoid macros)

Comment: As always with a "how can I shoehorn non-polymorphic things into a container" question, you need to work out how you would actually use the container if such a thing were possible.  If you iterated through the items, what would you want to be able to do with them?

Comment: @Oli: Let's say based on the type of key and/or value I would like to print them out or serialize to disk. Now, how would you "shoehorn" it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/variant.html) if the set of types is determined in advance. If not, then [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/any.html) might do the trick.

Comment: Indded, or `boost::any` otherwise.

Comment: Ah, boost::any is a familiar beast. Will look into both of these suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From your question and subsequent comments that clarify matters, the following would do what you're asking for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

// All class-template instantiations derive from this
struct AbstractPair
{
    virtual std::string serialize() const = 0;
};

template<typename K, typename V>
struct Pair : public AbstractPair
{
public:
    Pair(K key, V value) : key(key), value(value) {}

    std::string serialize() const
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "Key: " << key << ", Value: " << value;
        return ss.str();
    }
    K key;
    V value;
};


int main()
{
    // Vector of pointers-to-abstract-base
    std::vector<AbstractPair *> v;

    // Create derived objects (instantiate class template)
    AbstractPair *p1 = new Pair<int,int>(5,10);
    AbstractPair *p2 = new Pair<float,std::string>(3.2f, "Hello");

    // Valid, and type-safe
    v.push_back(p1);
    v.push_back(p2);

    // Demonstrate polymorphism
    for(std::vector<AbstractPair *>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << (*it)->serialize() << std::endl;
    }

    // Boilerplate cleanup
    delete p1;
    delete p2;
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: beat me to it... ach well.. :)

Comment: @kvs: Well, you should mention that kind of restriction in your question!  Also: why not?  (proof-of-concept code above could be done even more cleanly with smart pointers)

Comment: I thought the example and the question implied containers with value semantics. It's easy to shoehorn any type into an STL container with pointers and polymorphism. I am looking for proper value semantics and compile time type-checking etc. (See boost::variant documentation, for example, for list of reasons why pointer & polymorphism may not be suitable). I am writing a library not a program.

Comment: @kvs: Your question doesn't really imply this at all, but fair enough.  My "solution" above doesn't suffer from the problems described in the boost variant docs; it is type-safe, and involves no down-casts (at least, not to solve the problem as you've stated it!).  If you can edit your question so as to describe why there could be a problem, then I can respond further...